# Qt: resizing a QLabel containing a QPixmap while keeping its aspect ratio

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qlabel

I use a QLabel to display the content of a bigger, dynamically changing QPixmap to the user. It would be nice to make this label smaller/larger depending on the space available. The screen size is not always as big as the QPixmap.

How can I modify the `QSizePolicy` and `sizeHint()` of the QLabel to resize the QPixmap while keeping the aspect ratio of the original QPixmap?

I can't modify `sizeHint()` of the QLabel, setting the `minimumSize()` to zero does not help. Setting `hasScaledContents()` on the QLabel allows growing, but breaks the aspect ratio thingy...

Subclassing QLabel did help, but this solution adds too much code for just a simple problem...

Any smart hints how to accomplish this *without* subclassing?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

In order to change the label size you can select an appropriate size policy for the label like expanding or minimum expanding.

You can scale the pixmap by keeping its aspect ratio every time it changes:

```
QPixmap p; // load pixmap
// get label dimensions
int w = label->width();
int h = label->height();

// set a scaled pixmap to a w x h window keeping its aspect ratio 
label->setPixmap(p.scaled(w,h,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
```

There are two places where you should add this code:

- When the pixmap is updated
- In the `resizeEvent` of the widget that contains the label

Comment: hm yes, this was basically the core when I subclassed `QLabel`. But I thought this use case (showing Images with arbitrary size in Widgets of arbitrary size) would be common enough to have something like it implementable via existing code...

Comment: AFAIK this functionality is not provided by default. The most elegant way to achieve what you want is to subclass `QLabel`. Otherwise you can use the code of my answer in a slot/function which will be called every time the pixmap changes.

Comment: since I want the `QLabel` to automagically expand based on the users resizing of the `QMainWindow` and the available space, I can't use the signal/slot solution -- I can't model an _expanding_ policy this way.

Comment: You have to do in the resizeEvent of the widget where the label is.

Comment: In order to be able to scale down as well, you need to add this call:
`label->setMinimumSize(1, 1)`

Comment: Under certain circumstances you can use the `image` stylesheet element [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70858333/616460).

Answer (score 47):

I have polished this missing subclass of `QLabel`.  It is awesome and works well.

aspectratiopixmaplabel.h

```
#ifndef ASPECTRATIOPIXMAPLABEL_H
#define ASPECTRATIOPIXMAPLABEL_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QResizeEvent>

class AspectRatioPixmapLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit AspectRatioPixmapLabel(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual int heightForWidth( int width ) const;
    virtual QSize sizeHint() const;
    QPixmap scaledPixmap() const;
public slots:
    void setPixmap ( const QPixmap & );
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *);
private:
    QPixmap pix;
};

#endif // ASPECTRATIOPIXMAPLABEL_H
```

aspectratiopixmaplabel.cpp

```
#include "aspectratiopixmaplabel.h"
//#include <QDebug>

AspectRatioPixmapLabel::AspectRatioPixmapLabel(QWidget *parent) :
    QLabel(parent)
{
    this->setMinimumSize(1,1);
    setScaledContents(false);
}

void AspectRatioPixmapLabel::setPixmap ( const QPixmap & p)
{
    pix = p;
    QLabel::setPixmap(scaledPixmap());
}

int AspectRatioPixmapLabel::heightForWidth( int width ) const
{
    return pix.isNull() ? this->height() : ((qreal)pix.height()*width)/pix.width();
}

QSize AspectRatioPixmapLabel::sizeHint() const
{
    int w = this->width();
    return QSize( w, heightForWidth(w) );
}

QPixmap AspectRatioPixmapLabel::scaledPixmap() const
{
    return pix.scaled(this->size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
}

void AspectRatioPixmapLabel::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * e)
{
    if(!pix.isNull())
        QLabel::setPixmap(scaledPixmap());
}
```

Hope that helps!
(Updated `resizeEvent`, per @dmzl's answer)

Comment: Thanks, works great. I would also add ``QLabel::setPixmap(pix.scaled(this->size(),
                                 Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));`` to the ``setPixmap()`` method.

Comment: You are right.  I made the assumption that you want to store the highest quality version of the pixmap, and that you call setPixmap before resizing/anchoring the label.  To reduce code duplication, I probably should put `this->resize(width(), height());` at the tail end of the `setPixmap` function.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Would you have any suggestions on how I can set a "preferred" size to the QPixmap so that it does not take the maximum resolution on the first launch of the application?

Comment: Use layouts and stretch rules.

Comment: Could you elaborate on recommended rules? I tried a lot of things in Designer but without success. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is fantastic! I translated it to Python/PySide to solve a problem that had been bugging me for hours: https://gist.github.com/grayshirt/510f32bb63dac9505f0d. My version does have an issue where you can see the image visibly growing for a second or two if the widget is upsized very quickly.

Comment: I also can't come up with a suitable layout or suitable stretch rules for this. It starts with the picture's original resolution, and cannot shrink below that. My `AspectRatioPixmapLabel` is in a pair of nested `QVBoxLayout` and `QHBoxlayout`.

Comment: Two problems: 1. if the source image is .svg it looks horrible if it is stretched far. 2. it is not centered but aligned to the left.

Comment: Great option! Thanks for contributing. For future users, I had to unset the [`scaledContents`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#scaledContents-prop) property to get this to work properly.

Comment: Sounds good. Feel free to add another edit to the code to get that in the constructor.

Comment: Great answer! For anyone needing to work on High DPI screens simply change scaledPixmap() to do: `auto scaled = pix.scaled(this->size() * devicePixelRatioF(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
scaled.setDevicePixelRatio(devicePixelRatioF());
return scaled;` This also works on normally scaled screens.

Comment: Under certain circumstances you can avoid the subclassing and use the `image` stylesheet element on a vanilla QLabel [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70858333/616460).

Answer (score 23):

I just use `contentsMargin` to fix the aspect ratio.

```
#pragma once

#include <QLabel>

class AspectRatioLabel : public QLabel
{
public:
    explicit AspectRatioLabel(QWidget* parent = nullptr, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags());
    ~AspectRatioLabel();

public slots:
    void setPixmap(const QPixmap& pm);

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) override;

private:
    void updateMargins();

    int pixmapWidth = 0;
    int pixmapHeight = 0;
};
```

```
#include "AspectRatioLabel.h"

AspectRatioLabel::AspectRatioLabel(QWidget* parent, Qt::WindowFlags f) : QLabel(parent, f)
{
}

AspectRatioLabel::~AspectRatioLabel()
{
}

void AspectRatioLabel::setPixmap(const QPixmap& pm)
{
    pixmapWidth = pm.width();
    pixmapHeight = pm.height();

    updateMargins();
    QLabel::setPixmap(pm);
}

void AspectRatioLabel::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    updateMargins();
    QLabel::resizeEvent(event);
}

void AspectRatioLabel::updateMargins()
{
    if (pixmapWidth <= 0 || pixmapHeight <= 0)
        return;

    int w = this->width();
    int h = this->height();

    if (w <= 0 || h <= 0)
        return;

    if (w * pixmapHeight > h * pixmapWidth)
    {
        int m = (w - (pixmapWidth * h / pixmapHeight)) / 2;
        setContentsMargins(m, 0, m, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        int m = (h - (pixmapHeight * w / pixmapWidth)) / 2;
        setContentsMargins(0, m, 0, m);
    }
}
```

Works perfectly for me so far. You're welcome.

Comment: Just used this and it works like a charm! Also, pretty clever use of the layout manager. Should be the accepted answer since all the others have flaws in corner cases.

Comment: While non-intuitively clever, this answer solves a fundamentally *different* question: "How much internal padding should we add between a label whose size is already well-known and the pixmap contained in that label so as to preserve the aspect ratio of that pixmap?" Every other answer solves the original question: "To what size should we resize a label containing a pixmap so as to preserve the aspect ratio of that pixmap?" This answer requires the label's size to be predetermined somehow (e.g., with a fixed size policy), which is undesirable or even infeasible in many use cases.

Comment: That's the way to go for HiResolution (a.k.a "retina") displays - it's much better than downscaling the QPixmap.

Comment: Maybe I'm a little too focused on making code express high-level meaning for maintainability's sake but wouldn't it make more sense to use `QSize` instead of `...Width` and `...Height`? If nothing else, that'd make your early-return checks a simple `QSize::isEmpty` call. `QPixmap` and `QWidget` both have `size` methods to retrieve the width and height as a `QSize`.

Comment: @ssokolow Yes that sounds better - feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: this worked really nice in pyside6

Answer (score 8):

Adapted from Timmmm to PYQT5

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtGui import QResizeEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel


class Label(QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Label, self).__init__()
        self.pixmap_width: int = 1
        self.pixmapHeight: int = 1

    def setPixmap(self, pm: QPixmap) -> None:
        self.pixmap_width = pm.width()
        self.pixmapHeight = pm.height()

        self.updateMargins()
        super(Label, self).setPixmap(pm)

    def resizeEvent(self, a0: QResizeEvent) -> None:
        self.updateMargins()
        super(Label, self).resizeEvent(a0)

    def updateMargins(self):
        if self.pixmap() is None:
            return
        pixmapWidth = self.pixmap().width()
        pixmapHeight = self.pixmap().height()
        if pixmapWidth <= 0 or pixmapHeight <= 0:
            return
        w, h = self.width(), self.height()
        if w <= 0 or h <= 0:
            return

        if w * pixmapHeight > h * pixmapWidth:
            m = int((w - (pixmapWidth * h / pixmapHeight)) / 2)
            self.setContentsMargins(m, 0, m, 0)
        else:
            m = int((h - (pixmapHeight * w / pixmapWidth)) / 2)
            self.setContentsMargins(0, m, 0, m)
```

Comment: Worked for me. But we do not need self.pixmap_width and self.pixmapHeight. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If your image is a resource or a file you don't need to subclass anything; just set `image` in the label's stylesheet; and it will be scaled to fit the label while keeping its aspect ratio, and will track any size changes made to the label. You can optionally use `image-position` to move the image to one of the edges.

It doesn't fit the OP's case of a dynamically updated pixmap (I mean, you can set different resources whenever you want but they still have to be resources), but it's a good method if you're using pixmaps from resources.

Stylesheet example:

```
image: url(:/resource/path);
image-position: right center; /* optional: default is centered. */
```

In code (for example):

```
QString stylesheet = "image:url(%1);image-position:right center;";
existingLabel->setStyleSheet(stylesheet.arg(":/resource/path"));
```

Or you can just set the stylesheet property right in Designer:

[image]
<sup>*Icon source: [Designspace Team via Flaticon](https://www.flaticon.com/premium-icon/research_5080919)*</sup>

The caveat is that it won't scale the image larger, only smaller, so make sure your image is bigger than your range of sizes if you want it to grow (note that it can support SVG, which can improve quality).

The label's size can be controlled as per usual: either use size elements in the stylesheet or use the standard layout and size policy strategies.

See [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#image-prop) for details.

This style has been present since early Qt (position was added in 4.3 circa 2007 but image was around before then).

Answer (score 6):

I tried using phyatt's `AspectRatioPixmapLabel` class, but experienced a few problems:

- Sometimes my app entered an infinite loop of resize events. I traced this back to the call of `QLabel::setPixmap(...)` inside the resizeEvent method, because `QLabel` actually calls `updateGeometry` inside `setPixmap`, which may trigger resize events...
- `heightForWidth` seemed to be ignored by the containing widget (a `QScrollArea` in my case) until I started setting a size policy for the label, explicitly calling `policy.setHeightForWidth(true)`
- I want the label to never grow more than the original pixmap size
- `QLabel`'s implementation of `minimumSizeHint()` does some magic for labels containing text, but always resets the size policy to the default one, so I had to overwrite it

That said, here is my solution. I found that I could just use `setScaledContents(true)` and let `QLabel` handle the resizing.
Of course, this depends on the containing widget / layout honoring the `heightForWidth`.

aspectratiopixmaplabel.h

```
#ifndef ASPECTRATIOPIXMAPLABEL_H
#define ASPECTRATIOPIXMAPLABEL_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QPixmap>

class AspectRatioPixmapLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit AspectRatioPixmapLabel(const QPixmap &pixmap, QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual int heightForWidth(int width) const;
    virtual bool hasHeightForWidth() { return true; }
    virtual QSize sizeHint() const { return pixmap()->size(); }
    virtual QSize minimumSizeHint() const { return QSize(0, 0); }
};

#endif // ASPECTRATIOPIXMAPLABEL_H
```

aspectratiopixmaplabel.cpp

```
#include "aspectratiopixmaplabel.h"

AspectRatioPixmapLabel::AspectRatioPixmapLabel(const QPixmap &pixmap, QWidget *parent) :
    QLabel(parent)
{
    QLabel::setPixmap(pixmap);
    setScaledContents(true);
    QSizePolicy policy(QSizePolicy::Maximum, QSizePolicy::Maximum);
    policy.setHeightForWidth(true);
    this->setSizePolicy(policy);
}

int AspectRatioPixmapLabel::heightForWidth(int width) const
{
    if (width > pixmap()->width()) {
        return pixmap()->height();
    } else {
        return ((qreal)pixmap()->height()*width)/pixmap()->width();
    }
}
```

Comment: While preferable for edge cases in which the parent widget and/or layout containing this label respect the `heightForWidth` property, this answer fails for the general case in which the parent widget and/or layout containing this label do *not* respect the `heightForWidth` property. Which is unfortunate, as this answer is otherwise preferable to [phyatt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/999943/phyatt)'s [long-standing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22618496/2809027).

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this to work as expected. It is essential to override `sizeHint` as well as `resizeEvent`, and to set the minimum size and the size policy.
`setAlignment` is used to centre the image in the control either horizontally or vertically when the control is a different aspect ratio to the image.

```
class ImageDisplayWidget(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, max_enlargement=2.0):
        super().__init__()
        self.max_enlargement = max_enlargement
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setMinimumSize(1, 1)
        self.__image = None

    def setImage(self, image):
        self.__image = image
        self.resize(self.sizeHint())
        self.update()

    def sizeHint(self):
        if self.__image:
            return self.__image.size() * self.max_enlargement
        else:
            return QSize(1, 1)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        if self.__image:
            pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(self.__image)
            scaled = pixmap.scaled(event.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            self.setPixmap(scaled)
        super().resizeEvent(event)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Qt documentations has an [Image Viewer example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-imageviewer-example.html) which demonstrates handling resizing images inside a `QLabel`. The basic idea is to use `QScrollArea` as a container for the `QLabel` and if needed use `label.setScaledContents(bool)` and `scrollarea.setWidgetResizable(bool)` to fill available space and/or ensure QLabel inside is resizable.
Additionally, to resize QLabel while honoring aspect ratio use:

```c
label.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(width, height, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation));
```

The `width` and `height` can be set based on `scrollarea.width()` and `scrollarea.height()`.
In this way there is no need to subclass QLabel.

Comment: That example does not maintain the aspect ratio while resizing automatically. It allows manual resizing while maintaining the aspect ratio, and can resize automatically without maintaining the aspect ratio, but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing new here really.

I mixed the accepted reply
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8212120/11413792
and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43936590/11413792
which uses `setContentsMargins`,
but just coded it a bit my own way.

```
/**
 * @brief calcMargins Calculate the margins when a rectangle of one size is centred inside another
 * @param outside - the size of the surrounding rectanle
 * @param inside  - the size of the surrounded rectangle
 * @return the size of the four margins, as a QMargins
 */
QMargins calcMargins(QSize const outside, QSize const inside)
{
    int left = (outside.width()-inside.width())/2;
    int top  = (outside.height()-inside.height())/2;
    int right = outside.width()-(inside.width()+left);
    int bottom = outside.height()-(inside.height()+top);

    QMargins margins(left, top, right, bottom);
    return margins;
}
```

A function calculates the margins required to centre one rectangle inside another. Its a pretty generic function that could be used for lots of things though I have no idea what.

Then `setContentsMargins` becomes easy to use with a couple of extra lines
which many people would combine into one.

```
QPixmap scaled = p.scaled(this->size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
QMargins margins = calcMargins(this->size(), scaled.size());
this->setContentsMargins(margins);
setPixmap(scaled);
```

It may interest somebody ... I needed to handle `mousePressEvent` and to know where I am within the image.

```
void MyClass::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    QMargins margins = contentsMargins();

    QPoint labelCoordinateClickPos = ev->pos();
    QPoint pixmapCoordinateClickedPos = labelCoordinateClickPos - QPoint(margins.left(),margins.top());
    ... more stuff here
}
```

My large image was from a camera and I obtained the relative coordinates [0, 1) by dividing by the width of the pixmap and then multiplied up by the width of the original image.

Answer (score 0):

This is the port of @phyatt's class to PySide2.

Apart from porting i added an additional aligment in the resizeEvent in order to make the newly resized image position properly in the available space.

```python
from typing import Union

from PySide2.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap, QResizeEvent
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QLabel, QWidget

class QResizingPixmapLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent: Union[QWidget, None] = ...):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(1,1)
        self.setScaledContents(False)
        self._pixmap: Union[QPixmap, None] = None

    def heightForWidth(self, width:int) -> int:
        if self._pixmap is None:
            return self.height()
        else:
            return self._pixmap.height() * width / self._pixmap.width()

    def scaledPixmap(self) -> QPixmap:
        scaled = self._pixmap.scaled(
            self.size() * self.devicePixelRatioF(),
            Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
            Qt.SmoothTransformation
        )
        scaled.setDevicePixelRatio(self.devicePixelRatioF());
        return scaled;

    def setPixmap(self, pixmap: QPixmap) -> None:
        self._pixmap = pixmap
        super().setPixmap(pixmap)

    def sizeHint(self) -> QSize:
        width = self.width()
        return QSize(width, self.heightForWidth(width))

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QResizeEvent) -> None:
        if self._pixmap is not None:
            super().setPixmap(self.scaledPixmap())
            self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
```