# Qt Overriding QLabel PaintEvent

Tags: c++, image, qt

I've been struggling with this problem for the past couple of days. I want to be able to grow and shrink whatever the assigned Pixmap is in a QLabel as the user resizes the window. The issue is preserving the aspect ratio and image quality. Another user on here suggested that I reimplement the paint event for the label - but I'm still very lost. I'm not even sure if I have overridden the paintEvent correctly. I would kill for a bit of sample code here.

This is where I'm at:

```
void MyLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
{
    //if this widget is assigned a pixmap
    //paint that pixmap at the size of the parent, aspect ratio preserved
    //otherwise, nothing
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation of a `QLabel` subclass that scales its pixmap content while keeping its aspect ratio. It is implemented based on the way `QLabel::paintEvent` [is implemented](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qlabel.cpp#n1004).

If you are using it in a layout you can also set its size policy to [`QSizePolicy::Expanding`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum), so that additional space in the layout is taken up by the `QLabel` for a larger display of the pixmap content.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

class PixmapLabel : public QLabel{
public:
    explicit PixmapLabel(QWidget* parent=nullptr):QLabel(parent){
        //By default, this class scales the pixmap according to the label's size
        setScaledContents(true);
    }
    ~PixmapLabel(){}

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event);
private:
    //QImage to cache the pixmap()
    //to avoid constructing a new QImage on every scale operation
    QImage cachedImage;
    //used to cache the last scaled pixmap
    //to avoid calling scale again when the size is still at the same
    QPixmap scaledPixmap;
    //key for the currently cached QImage and QPixmap
    //used to make sure the label was not set to another QPixmap
    qint64 cacheKey{0};
};

//based on the implementation of QLabel::paintEvent
void PixmapLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
    //if this is assigned to a pixmap
    if(pixmap() && !pixmap()->isNull()){
        QStyle* style= PixmapLabel::style();
        QPainter painter(this);
        drawFrame(&painter);
        QRect cr = contentsRect();
        cr.adjust(margin(), margin(), -margin(), -margin());
        int align= QStyle::visualAlignment(layoutDirection(), alignment());
        QPixmap pix;
        if(hasScaledContents()){ //if scaling is enabled
            QSize scaledSize= cr.size() * devicePixelRatioF();
            //if scaledPixmap is invalid
            if(scaledPixmap.isNull() || scaledPixmap.size()!=scaledSize
                    || pixmap()->cacheKey()!=cacheKey){
                //if cachedImage is also invalid
                if(pixmap()->cacheKey() != cacheKey){
                    //reconstruct cachedImage
                    cachedImage= pixmap()->toImage();
                }
                QImage scaledImage= cachedImage.scaled(
                            scaledSize, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
                scaledPixmap= QPixmap::fromImage(scaledImage);
                scaledPixmap.setDevicePixelRatio(devicePixelRatioF());
            }
            pix= scaledPixmap;
        } else { // no scaling, Just use pixmap()
            pix= *pixmap();
        }
        QStyleOption opt;
        opt.initFrom(this);
        if(!isEnabled())
            pix= style->generatedIconPixmap(QIcon::Disabled, pix, &opt);
        style->drawItemPixmap(&painter, cr, align, pix);
    } else { //otherwise (if the label is not assigned to a pixmap)
        //call base paintEvent
        QLabel::paintEvent(event);
    }
}

//DEMO program
QPixmap generatePixmap(QSize size) {
    QPixmap pixmap(size);
    pixmap.fill(Qt::white);
    QPainter p(&pixmap);
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    p.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 10));
    p.drawEllipse(pixmap.rect());
    p.setPen(QPen(Qt::red, 2));
    p.drawLine(pixmap.rect().topLeft(), pixmap.rect().bottomRight());
    p.drawLine(pixmap.rect().topRight(), pixmap.rect().bottomLeft());
    return pixmap;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);


    QPixmap pixmap= generatePixmap(QSize(1280, 960));
    PixmapLabel label;
    label.setPixmap(pixmap);
    label.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    label.setMinimumSize(320, 240);
    label.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I think this is better than the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8212120/2666212), as the `QLabel` here takes care of resizing its pixmap. So, there is no need to resize it manually every time the parent widget is resized  and everytime a new pixmap is set on it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this cleared everything up.

Comment: I think it has memory leak , because QLabel has not virtual destructure.

Comment: @H.M, `QLabel`'s destructor **is** virtual, see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#dtor.QLabel). The destructor has to be virtual because the class inherits from `QWidget` and `QObject`, and the lifetime of such objects is often managed polymorphically in the form of [`QObject` trees](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html).

Comment: Also, as a matter of fact, the demo example I provided doesn't require the destructor to be virtual, since it never destroys a `PixmapLabel` object through a base class pointer...

Comment: [QLabel source code](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qlabel.h.html#_ZN6QLabelD1Ev) @Mike , As we can see source codes , it is not virtual.

Comment: @Mike your right if we explicit pass parent in constructor's parent , we have not memory leak.

Comment: Hi @H.M, thanks for sharing your concerns :). However, I have to disagree: `QObject` is a base class of `QLabel`, and `QObject` has a virtual dtor, see [here](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h.html#_ZN7QObjectD1Ev)...

Answer (score 0):

First of all I wanted to say thanks to Mike.

Additionally I would like to add to his answer from 21.10.2016 - however I am not able to add a comment as of yet - thus here is a full fledged answer. [If anyone is able to move this to the comment section, feel free.]

I also added an overwrite of the other constructor of QLabel and the window flags [with default arguments as in QLabel] and added the Q_OBJECT macro, as to be compatible to the Qt framework:

Header:

```
class PixmapLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PixmapLabel(QWidget* parent=nullptr, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags());
    explicit PixmapLabel(const QString &text, QWidget *parent = nullptr, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags());
   ...
}
```

Module:

```
PixmapLabel::PixmapLabel(QString const & text, QWidget * parent, Qt::WindowFlags f) :
    QLabel(text, parent, f)
{
    //By default, this class scales the pixmap according to the label's size
     setScaledContents(true);
}
```