# Qt - QLabel won't resize with fixed ratio

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-designer, qlabel

#### Introduction

I am working with the Designer inside the Qt Creator and have a `QMainWindow` with a `QLabel` in it. Because the program loads pictures and displays them inside the label i want that the label resizes with a ratio of 1.25 inside setted boundaries when expanding or shrinking the `QMainWindow`. The label should resize INDEPENDENT, again INDEPENDENT from its content.

What i want:

- Open the main window for first time:
  width: 640, height: 512
- Shrinking the main window:
  label shrinks with constant ratio (640/512) till minimum size (320 x 256)
- Expanding the main window:
  label expands with constant ratio (640/512) till maximum size (1280 x 1024)

#### 1. Approach:

Therefor i...

- added a `QLabel`(called `imageLabel`) inside the `centralWidget` of the `QMainWindow`
- set the `centralWidget`'s layout to grid layout (`QGridLayout`)
- sed the following properties to the `QLabel`:

  - geometry - Can not set the values because of grid layout usages!
  - minimumSize > width: 320, height: 256 (Minimum values)
  - maximumSize > width: 1280, height: 1024 (Maximum values)
  - sizePolicy > Horizontal Policy == Vertical Policy == Expanding

Element structure:

[image: Initial Element structure]

This doesn't work because i can not set an initial size in the 'geometry' section. The label does not scale with fixed ratio although it respects minimum and maximum values.

#### 2. Approach:

Following [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8212120/5233188) answer i set an initial pixmap:

```
QPixmap p;
ui->imageLabel->setPixmap(p.scaled(640, 512, Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
```

Which didn't change anything.

#### 3. Approach:

I also applied the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22618496/5233188)'s class and promoted it to the widget:

[image: Structure after promoting 'AspectRatioPixmapLabel' class]

That didn't change anything too.

#### 4. Approach:

I then combined the 2. and 3. approach and set an initial pixmap which...

...didn't change anything.

Here is what it does for the approaches 1. - 4.:

[image: Approaches 1. - 4. - It's all the same]

#### 5. Approach

Adding the label of 4. approach into a widget:

[image: 5. approach element structure]

Well the label doesn't resize at all:

[image: 5. approach result]

So, how can get the label to have an initial size of 640 x 512 and scale with fixed ratio between 1280 x 1024 and 320 x 256 ?

Comment: `QLabel::setScaledContents(bool)` ?

Comment: @MohammadKanan (`ui->imageLabel->setScaledContents(true)`) Doesn't work either. Still like in approaches 1. - 4.

Comment: If a label is part of a layout its size depends on the size of the widget (or window) to which the layout belongs. So you have to calculate and set the initial size of this widget (or window) instead.

Comment: This may help: [`QSizePolicy::setHeightForWidth`](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#setHeightForWidth)

Comment: @scopchanov I really think this is a pretty bad idea. There are spaces and borders  between the label and the widget which can change when adding other widgets or changing the spaces, alignment and other things. Adding a calculation for the belonging widget (not the label) would be inconvenient.

Comment: @goulashsoup, it is not an idea. I've mentioned a fact.

Comment: @eyllanesc I only had time to get back to it just now. Your soultion works. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to install an eventFilter to the centralwidget so doing the required calculation is set the size.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->centralWidget->installEventFilter(this);
    ui->imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/image.png"));
    ui->imageLabel->setScaledContents(true);
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    const float ratio = 1.25;
    if(watched == ui->centralWidget && event->type() == QEvent::Resize
            && ui->centralWidget->width() > 0
            && ui->centralWidget->height() > 0){
        float central_ratio = 1.0*ui->centralWidget->width()/ui->centralWidget->height();        QSize s;
        if(central_ratio > ratio){
            s = QSize(ratio*ui->centralWidget->height(), ui->centralWidget->height());
        }
        else{
            s = QSize(ui->centralWidget->width(), ui->centralWidget->width()/ratio);
        }
        ui->imageLabel->resize(s);
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(watched, event);
}
```